# numpy and solving symmetric systems

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a symmetric matrix `A` and a vector `b` and want to find `A^(-1) b`. Now, this is well-known to be doable in time `O(N^2)` (where `N` is the dimension of the vector\matrix), and I believe that in **MATLAB** this can be done as `b\A`. But all I can find in python is `numpy.linalg.solve()` which will do Gaussian elimination, which is `O(N^3)`. I must not be looking in the right place...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the complexity of MATLAB's `b\A`?

Comment: It should be quadratic - I suppose some tests are in order :)

Comment: `scipy.linalg` and `scipy.sparse.linalg` might have alternatives.  Don't count on the functions detecting the special condtion(s); look for explicit mentions in the docs.  Typically the python code delegates the action to BLAS/etc functions, but it has to choose the right one to gain speed.

Answer (score 2):

[**`scipy.linalg.solve`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html#scipy.linalg.solve) has an argument to make it assume a symmetric matrix:

```
x = scipy.linalg.solve(A, b, assume_a="sym")
```

If you know your matrix is not just symmetric but positive definite you can give this stronger assumption instead, as `"pos"`.

Comment: It won't work for PSD matrices, namely, in case they have a zero eigen vector.