# Solving ill-conditioned symmetric system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

As the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66269318/numpy-and-solving-symmetric-system) tells us, a symmetric positive definite linear system can be solved in quadratic time (using conjugate gradients). But now, suppose our system is ill-conditioned. Then, we know that we can approximate the solution to `A x = b` by `x = pinv(A) b.` But can this be done in sub-cubic time?

Comment: scicomp.stackexchange.com?

Comment: see equation 26 of this: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf; convergence decays with condition number.

Comment: @user14717 Yes, I am aware of that. However, I can imagine a way to find the low eigenvalues (using some sort of Jacobi iteration, which is O(n^2)) and then doing the pseudo-inverse quickly.